# Bypassing proxy in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron, atom-editor

Im having issues in bypassing proxy. I’m new to both JavaScript and Electron.

I'm either facing this issue (pic below) or a blank white screen will be loaded.

[image]

My pacfile.pac :

```
    function findProxyForURL(url, host) {

// If the hostname matches, send direct.
if (dnsDomainIs(host, “http://000.00.0.0:0000”) ||
shExpMatch(host, “(*.domain.com)”))
return “DIRECT”;

}
```

my index.js:

```
 const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
var fs = require('fs');
var pac = require('pac-resolver');
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow
let ProxyFunc
let pacVariable

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.

  //proxy: "http://000.00.0.0:0000"
// /* src="https://domain.name.com/#/random/login"  */
  /*mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:"http://000.00.0.0:0000"}, function () {
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://domain.name.com/#/random/login');
});*/

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('proxy-bypass-list', '*.google.com;*domain.name.com;');
pacVariable = new pacfile();
pacVariable.findProxyForURL("https://domain.name.com/#/random/login", "*domain.name.com");
//ProxyFunc = new FindProxyForURL("https://domain.name.com/#/random/login","domain.name.com");
mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:"http://000.00.0.0:0000",proxyBypassRules:"domain.name.com"}, function () {
  mainWindow.loadURL(path.join('file://', __dirname, 'index.html'));
});

/*mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:"http://000.00.0.0:0000"}, function () {
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://domain.name.com/#/random/login');
});*/

mainWindow.openDevTools({ mode: 'bottom' });
  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Comment: you haven't imported the pac file

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: after adding var pacfile = require('./pacfile.pac');  im getting Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: shExpMatch is not defined
. I have installed npm proxy agent as well as npm pack resolver

Comment: try the answer. you can't require a pacfile. and you have to install pac-resolver. `npm install pac-resolver`

Comment: has this helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `pacVariable = new pacfile()` with

```
var FindProxyForURL = pac(fs.readFileSync('pacfile.pac'));
FindProxyForURL('https://domain.name.com/#/random/login').then((res) => {
  console.log(res);      

});
```

refer the [docs](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-pac-resolver) for API

FindProxyForURL is a promise, so you'll have to write the code that requires the response inside the `.then`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your solution and didn't get the results, later found out that there are some other issues are also there from our web app side. I will recheck this part once they are fixed.